# Analyzing the operations of a savedmodel in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I need to write a program that loads a pretrained model in SavedModel  format and analyzes the types of operations present in the graph.

In TF1 I used graph.get_operations() to get the list of all nodes and  I could even modify the graph using  tf.contrib.graph_editor. In TF2 these APIs don't work anymore: the list of operations  doesn't provide useful information (I can't distinguish a Matmul from an  Add node for example) and the tf.contrib.graph_editor has been deleted.
I know that in TF2 I can still "explore" the model visually with tensorboard  and/or the debugger, but I need to write a program that can do this analysis automatically.

Is there any way to do that using python?

Thank you.